# Android glVertexAttribPointer Stride/Offset

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, shader

I have a packed vertex buffer containing postion coordinates aswell as color values for a vertex in the format {x, y, z, r, g, b}.

I am able to pass the correct xyz values to the Vertex Shader. Unexpectedly the rendered square comes out white.

What is the correct way to use glVertexAttribPointer(...) to render from a packed vertex buffer?

Code:

```
public float vertices[] = {
        1, 1, 1, 255, 255, 255,
        -1, 1, 1, 255, 87, 255,
        -1, -1, 1, 87, 67, 255,
        1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0
};
public FloatBuffer verticesBuffer;

public int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 3,
        1, 2, 3
};
public IntBuffer indicesBuffer;

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
verticesBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
verticesBuffer.put(vertices);
verticesBuffer.position(0);

bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 4);
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
indicesBuffer = bb.asIntBuffer();
indicesBuffer.put(indices);
indicesBuffer.position(0);
```

---

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 notUsed) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(programId);

    verticesBuffer.position(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionHandle);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, (POS_SZ + COL_SZ) * FLOAT_SZ, verticesBuffer);

    verticesBuffer.position(POS_SZ);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexColorHandle);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexColorHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, (POS_SZ + COL_SZ) * FLOAT_SZ, verticesBuffer);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixHandle, 1, false, projectionMatrix, 0);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrixHandle, 1, false, viewMatrix, 0);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixHandle, 1, false, modelMatrix, 0);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indicesBuffer);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionHandle);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexColorHandle);
}
```

Shaders:

```
public static String VertexShader =
    "attribute vec3 a_Position;" +
    "attribute vec3 a_Color;" +
    "" +
    "uniform mat4 u_ProjectionMatrix;" +
    "uniform mat4 u_ViewMatrix;" +
    "uniform mat4 u_ModelMatrix;" +
    "" +
    "varying vec3 v_Color;" +
    "" +
    "void main()" +
    "{" +
        "gl_Position = u_ProjectionMatrix * u_ViewMatrix * u_ModelMatrix * vec4(a_Position, 1);" +
        "v_Color = a_Color;" +
    "}";
public static String FragmentShader =
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "" +
    "varying vec3 v_Color;" +
    "" +
    "void main()" +
    "{" +
        "gl_FragColor = vec4(1, v_Color);" +
    "}";
```

Comment: This has come up before, but I'm not sure how to best find one of the duplicates. Since you specify the colors as float values, they need to be normalized, meaning that they are in the range 0.0 to 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Reto Koradi, I had two issues...

The vertex color is passed in as values from *0-1*. The vertices array had to be:

```
public float vertices[] = {
        1.0f,   1.0f,   1.0f,   1.0f,   0.0f,   0.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f,   0.0f,   1.0f,   0.0f,
        -1.0f,  -1.0f,  1.0f,   0.0f,   0.0f,   1.0f,
        1.0f,   -1.0f,  1.0f,   0.0f,   0.0f,   0.0f,
};
```

Also  I had a minor issue in the Fragment Shader:

```
"gl_FragColor = vec4(1, v_Color);" +
```

It's (r, g, b, a), so it's supposed to be:

```
"gl_FragColor = vec4(v_Color, 1);" +
```